# Custom Cell not showing Data in UITabelView not using storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So im trying build app with no storyboard. I have made custom tableview cell class and trying display a title and image from an array. The code runs and even creates cells that number same as array but cells are blank. If anyone could have a look over this that would be great. Thanks

This is my custom cell

```
class CoffeeCell: UITableViewCell {

let cellImage = UIImageView()
let cellTitalBackground = UIView()
let cellTital = UILabel()


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9324248433, green: 0.9268818498, blue: 0.9366856217, alpha: 1)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.addSubview(cellImage)
    self.addSubview(cellTitalBackground)
    self.addSubview(cellTital)
    setUpCellImage()
    setUpCellTitalBackground()
    setUpCellTital()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


func setUpCell(Coffee: Coffee) {
    self.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: Coffee.image)
    self.cellTital.text = Coffee.tital
```

and here is the view controller code for table view

```
import UIKit

class CoffeeVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


let logoImage = UIImage(named: "DIYCoffeeLogoDark")
let logoImageView = UIImageView()
let pageHeader = UILabel()
let coffeeTableView = UITableView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    coffeeTableView.dataSource = self
    coffeeTableView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(pageHeader)
    view.addSubview(coffeeTableView)

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DataService.instance.coffees.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = coffeeTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CoffeeCell", for: indexPath) as? CoffeeCell {
            let coffee = DataService.instance.getCoffee()[indexPath.row]
            cell.setUpCell(Coffee: coffee)
            print ("it works")
            return cell
        } else {
            return CoffeeCell()
        }
```

Hope that all makes sense

here is added all the code for my cell class

```
import UIKit

class CoffeeCell: UITableViewCell {

let cellImage = UIImageView()
let cellTitalBackground = UIView()
let cellTital = UILabel()


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9324248433, green: 0.9268818498, blue: 0.9366856217, alpha: 1)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.addSubview(cellImage)
    self.addSubview(cellTitalBackground)
    self.addSubview(cellTital)
    setUpCellImage()
    setUpCellTitalBackground()
    setUpCellTital()
    layoutIfNeeded()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


func setUpCell(Coffee: Coffee) {
    self.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: Coffee.image)
    self.cellTital.text = Coffee.tital

}
func setUpCellImage() {
    cellImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cellImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    cellImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    cellImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    cellImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    cellImage.clipsToBounds = true
}

func setUpCellTitalBackground() {
    cellTitalBackground.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.7847549229)
    cellTitalBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellTitalBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    cellTitalBackground.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    cellTitalBackground.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    cellTitalBackground.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    cellTitalBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cellTitalBackground.layer.maskedCorners = .layerMaxXMinYCorner
}

func setUpCellTital() {
    cellTital.textColor = .black
    cellTital.textAlignment = .center
    cellTital.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 30)
    cellTital.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cellTital.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellTital.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellTitalBackground.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    cellTital.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellTitalBackground.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    cellTital.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellTitalBackground.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    cellTital.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellTitalBackground.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have already set the constranits right. You also need to set height of tableViewCells like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50 // whatever you want
    }
```

Comment: thanks yes I have put in a cell height of 150 and the cells display at the correct height but missing the image and label

Comment: Yes, because you don’t register cells. And in cellForRow method create new cell every time.

Comment: maybe because you have not set the constraints right for image and label.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code as follows. Looks like your image and title label frame is not updating when you assign the image and title. So, move your constraints and addsubView to setUpCell method.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9324248433, green: 0.9268818498, blue: 0.9366856217, alpha: 1)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 20

}

func setUpCell(Coffee: Coffee) {
    self.addSubview(cellImage)
    self.addSubview(cellTitalBackground)
    self.addSubview(cellTital)
    setUpCellImage()
    setUpCellTitalBackground()
    setUpCellTital()
    self.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: Coffee.image)
    self.cellTital.text = Coffee.title

}
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: sorry I missed that bit out of the code I posted here but yes I have done that. the print statement I put in to check what part of my cellForRowAt() code is running does print to console as well. But for some reason not display image or label

Comment: You have to set frame size for your image and label

Comment: please share the complete code of CoffeeCell class.

Comment: thanks yea I've just updated the post with all the code

Answer (score 0):

You have to check constraints set up properly for image and label and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to create UITableViewCell instance when it's nil

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = coffeeTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CoffeeCell", for: indexPath) as? CoffeeCell
    if cell == nil {
       cell = CoffeeCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "CoffeeCell")
    } 
    cell?.setUpCell(Coffee: coffee)
    return cell!
```

You use identifier to reuse cell, but for begining, the cell is nil, never created, so you have to create when cell is nil.

This is my custom cell and it's running well as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your input and help everyone

had another look and reason wasn't working in th custom cell I was overriding the awakeFromNib() function but because im not using storyboards I needed to use the init functions shown below.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setUpView()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

sorry was a silly mistake thanks again.